# context-based model and interaction terms

Tags: predictive-modeling

I have implemented a prediction model.
Now I am checking if I should split the model to two context-based models (men and women).
I have created a new binary feature that is relevant to only part of the women's group and it can affect the prediction accuracy for this group.
I don’t have a lot of data so I am not eager to split to context-based models.
I know that in this cases it is best to use an interaction terms features (womenxnewfeature) but this feature is only part of the women's’ group and I have heard that adding the feature as it is it’s not good.

Any suggestion on what I can do?

Comment: I believe adding some more code or defining what you are trying to achieve with proper explanation of the current approach would be helpful. imho **I have heard that adding the feature as it is it’s not good** is not a good explanation.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc I cant add code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have gender data, use it. You're right that it will probably be a binary dummy feature (i.e., male = 0 or 1, and so on). You can use gender directly as a predictive feature, and/or interact it with other variables. You don't need to split your dataset by gender. Adding *arbitrary information* increases the noise in your set and decreases model quality. But you can learn whether gender is arbitrary or not! Add gender and compare to a model without gender to see if there's any change.

Comment: when splitting to model to two and comparing the results I have found out an increase in 5% of AUC for the female and a decrease of 15% for the male in compare with regular model AUC. that's why I am trying to find a solution.